# CSS issue with <DIV>, trying to get layout working

Tags: css, html

I'm very bad with css, and I can't get this layout looking good:
[image]
Maybe you can help me with the code because mine is a complete disaster. I made that image in order to help you to understand what I want.

Thanks a lot for any help or code (better a code).

Comment: copy your code and css to pastebin (but I can tell you that the best is to do your css one step at a time while watching the results in the webdeveloper plugin for firefox)

Comment: are any of the sections scrollable?

Comment: @DomingSL are you still looking for solution , if so let me know we can easliy accomplish that with div , css.

Comment: @DomingSL ,that layout you are lookig should be pretty simple with both table and div structure.

Comment: @gov yes im still looking for a code with DIV, please if you can help me please respond. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First: if you are bad with css and all those layout stuff use: 
[The 960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)

(or at least try to learn and use)

And about background :
make in photoshop (or any other tool) image 1x2000px with those colors that you show us on picture and add that to css like this:

```
.body{
    background-image:url(background_image.jpg)
    background-repeat:repeat-x; 
}
```

Comment: Not a bad attempt to try to offer some helpful information for a question that really didn't have enough to get anything good from. I'll offer a +1 vote just for that, for a new user.

Comment: thanks... well to be perfectly honest, sometimes is pretty hard to ask the "good" question if you don't know what you are dealing with but you only now what you want to achieve.